# Remover texto DevExtreme

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Como posso remover o texto e deixar a penas a caixa de texto do meu formulário ?

Preciso remover o texto `Ban nome:`, preciso que fique apenas a caixa de texto(css ainda não está pronto)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Form<AgenciaViewModel>()
                .ID("formularioCadastro")
                .ShowValidationSummary(false)
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    items.AddGroup()
                    .Items(groupItems =>
                    {
                        groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Ban_codigo).CssClass("txtBanUf")
                        .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().OnKeyPress("key_press").Width("70px"));

                        groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Ban_Nome)
                        .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().ReadOnly(true).ID("txtBanName").OnKeyPress("key_press").Width("200px"));
```

Qual propriedade posso usar para isso?

Creio eu que esses texto vem da `ViewModel`, o Nº do Banco vem, então o Ban Nome deve vim também

`ViewModel` usada:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SoftluxWebCore.ViewModels.Tabelas.Financeiro
{
public class AgenciaViewModel
{
    public int? Bcx_codigo { get; set; }
    public int? mun_codigo { get; set; }

    public string Bcx_Nome { get; set; }

    public string Ban_Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nº do Banco")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o número do Banco")]
    [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Esse número é maior que 4 caracteres")]
    public string Ban_codigo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nº da Agência")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a agência do Banco")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Essa agência é maior que 10 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_agencia { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Dígito")]
    [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Essa agência é maior que 5 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_DigitoAgencia { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    [MaxLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Esse endereço é maior que 45 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_endereco { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Número")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Esse número é maior que 10 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_numero { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Bairro")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Essa agência é maior que 30 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_bairro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Essa cidade é maior que 35 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_cidade { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UF")]
    [MaxLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Essa UF é maior que 2 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_uf { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cep")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Esse cep é maior que 10 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_cep { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Esse telefone é maior que 15 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_telefone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fax")]
    [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Esse fax é maior que 15 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_fax { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Site")]  
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Esse site é maior que 100 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_Pagina { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contato")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Esse nome é maior que 25 caracteres")]
    public string Bcx_Contato { get; set; }

    public string Con_tpcadastro { get; set; }
    public int? Con_codigo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Con_nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vinculo")]
    public string Con_vinculo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fone")]
    public string Con_fone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "FAX")]
    public string Con_fax { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Celular")]
    public string Con_celular { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Con_email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Código de Criação")]
    public Nullable<int> usr_cod_criacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Criação")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> usr_dt_hr_criacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Código de Alteração")]
    public Nullable<int> usr_cod_alteracao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de Alteração")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> usr_dt_hr_alteracao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ativo")]
    public bool Bcx_situacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Código da Empresa")]
    public Nullable<int> Emp_codigo { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: De onde vem essa informação?

Comment: Creio que da ViewModel, vou editar a publicação

Comment: Eu tive a ideia de adicionar a propriedade display a ViewModel e passar valor vazio, porém ele ficará exibindo apenas " : ", pois exibe por padrão

Comment: Na verdade está faltando o DisplayName no     `public string Ban_Nome { get; set; }`

Comment: Mesmo que eu acrescente [Display(Name = " ")] ao campo, ele me traz " : " automaticamente

Comment: Mas alterando para `[Display(Name="Nome do Banco)]` ele funciona não?

Comment: Funciona, mas a minha intenção é que fique em branco, consegui resolver, vou posta solução

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver através de css

```
    .txtBanName > label
    {
         display: none !important;
    }
```

E mudei de id para class:

```
groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Ban_Nome).class("txtBanName")
                    .Editor(e => e.NumberBox().ReadOnly(true).OnKeyPress("key_press").Width("200px"));
```